# Meaning of repeat-prob in Speech Recognition Grammars

Tags: vxml

The spec for repeat probabilities in speech recognition grammars is at http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/#S2.5.1  This includes the following example:

```
<-- The rule reference to digit must occur two to four times -->
<-- with 80% probability of recurrence. -->
<item repeat="2-4" repeat-prob=".8">
   <ruleref uri="#digit"/> 
</item>
```

I'm trying to determine just what this example means.  The minimum length in-grammar utterance can contain two digits.  Does it then follow that the probability of a 3-digit utterance is 0.8 and a 4-digit utterance probability is 0.64?

Or am I misinterpreting what 'repeat-prob' means?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the specification is that there is a 20% probability that there is no repeated digits after the first two. There is an 80% probability that there will be a third or forth digit. There is no difference in probability between the chance of a third or forth digit.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I only saw your reply today, March 18!